from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import s3Hook ImportError: cannot import name 's3Hook' from 'airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3'
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.hooks import S3Hook
import boto3
import io
import pandas as pd 


default_arg={
    'owner':'airflows',
    'retires':1,
    'retry_delay':timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date':datetime(2024,5,21)
    }

dag = DAG(
    'upload_s3',
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    default_args=default_arg
)

def Extract_data():
    details = {
    'Name' : ['Ankit', 'Aishwarya', 'Shaurya', 'Shivangi'],
    'Age' : [23, 21, 22, 21],
    'University' : ['BHU', 'JNU', 'DU', 'BHU'],
}
    

    return details

def process_data(**context):
    data=context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids="Extract_data")
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['column1', 'column2', 'column3'])
    processed_data = df.apply("some_processing_function", axis=1)

    return processed_data


def load_s3(processed_data,**context):
    access_key = 'AKIA3FLDYXTUMLX3BNIH'
    secret_key = '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'

    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key=secret_key
    )
    s3=boto3.client('s3')
    csv_buffer = io.StringIO()
    process_data.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False)
    s3.put_object(
        Bucket="airflowstuff",
        Key="airflow.csv",
        Body=csv_buffer.getvalue()
    )



extract_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='Extract_data',
    python_callable=Extract_data,
    dag=dag
)

process_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='process_data',
    python_callable=process_data,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
)

upload_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='upload_s3',
    python_callable=load_s3,
    op_kwargs={'processed_data': process_task},
    dag=dag
)


extract_task>>process_task>>upload_task


we try to put the dataframe in s3 bucket in AWS so when we import s3 hook in Airflow which show the error and the code not run but i try lots of debugging and help to google but not proper explanation is provided by google and which they provide also create a same error
To solve the error how to import the s3hook in airflow
